# How to mount Publify at "/blog" instead of at root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, publify

Publify is the perfect gem for my needs at the moment, except I cannot figure out how to move it to "/blog".

I changed `root "articles#index` to `get "/blog", to: "articles#index"`, but all the internal references to the root path in the application lead to the wrong place.

How can I properly achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
root "articles#index"

get "/blog" => redirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

On way is to add `config.relative_url_root = "/blog"` to application.rb file. See more in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root).

The alternative idea is to leave the app like it is and use the webserver/passenger to run it in a subdirectory.